# Can ArcGIS Desktop or ArcPad use the Windows Location Provider?

Tags: gps, arcgis-desktop, arcpad, windows-7, windows-8

Are there any plans for ArcGIS Desktop or ArcMap to get the GPS Coordinates via the 'Windows Location Provider' in Windows 7/8 instead of reading a virtual com port?

Answer (score 1):

From a review of this [**ArcGIS Forum Discussion**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/75252-Using-ArcGIS-for-Windows-Mobile-with-the-Windows-sensor-location-API) it looks like Esri are working on it. My recommendation is to also pursue it through your local support and ArcGIS Ideas if that does not meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It's available in the [ArcPad 10.2 Beta](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/03/24/arcpad-10-2-beta-is-now-available/) if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to share, this here works.

http://www.centrafuse.com/centrafuse-localizer

Just installed the updated version in the forums.